# Why is this not updating the DB?

Tags: php, mysql

It out puts the the results of the equation but dose not update the DB?? I have another connection open in the code at this point via mysql...

```
<?php
if($user_new=='Yes'){
$end = strtotime('+1 month',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00')) - 1;
$now = time(); 
$time = $end - $now;//Seconds til end of month
$percent = $time / 2635200;
$minus_1 = 1 - $percent;

 $server = 'XXXXXXX';
 $user = 'XXXXXXX';
 $pass = 'XXXXXXXX';
 $db = 'XXXXXXX';

$con = mysqli_connect ($server, $user, $pass, $db);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE usermeta SET value=$minus_1 
WHERE user_id='$user_ID' AND meta_key='user_new_mo'");

$user_per = $global_bal * $minus_1;//2635200 = Seconds in 30.5 days
$minus_per = $global_bal - $user_per;
$echo = $minus_per * $user_ghs;
}

elseif($user_new>='0'){
$num_result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM usermeta WHERE user_id='$user_ID' AND meta_key='user_new_mo'", $hash_con);
$echo = $num_result;
}
```

Comment: Mixing `mysql` and `nysqli` may not be the cause here, but it is adding to the confusion. If you want to know why queries aren't working you should do some **error checking**. Look up `mysqli_error()` and make use of it.

Comment: 1) Are you sure tha tyou get proper id from `get_current_user_id()`? 2) What type is column `value` ?

Comment: if you'll write in your code `echo "UPDATE usermeta SET value=$minus_1 
WHERE user_id='$user_ID' AND meta_key='user_new_mo'"` and then run echoed query in console will it work?

Answer (score 2):

Try a prepared statement to help with variable substitution.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE usermeta SET value=? WHERE user_id=? AND meta_key=?");
$stmt->bind_param($minus_1,$user_ID,'user_new_mo');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql query you must want to differ the php variables and the string like this Eg.

```
mysql_query($con,"select * from users where userid='".$user_id."'")
```

For eg the if **$user_id**=ssoft then the query resembles like this,

```
select * from userid where userid='ssoft'.
```

IAM SURE IT WILL HELP YOU.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume first that you have no mysql errors (I see you're not checking that in your code)... Most probably your update problem (not updating) should have something to do with the $user_ID.
Check to make sure that "get_current_user_id()" returns a value that exists in the [user_id] column in your  table.

Next... If the "get_current_user_id()" isn't the problem, then the problem is in your query (I think this is most probable): whenever you have to deal with variables inside a string, use curly braces.
So, turn

```
WHERE user_id='$user_ID'
```

into

```
WHERE user_id='{$user_ID}'
```

Or simply concatenate it like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `x` WHERE `some_column` = '" . $someValue . "'";
```

Use of curly braces for variables inside a string is valid only if the string is wrapped in double quotes (your's is, so you're ok here), otherwise $someVar is simply the string *$someVar* (ie $string = '$someVar') as opposed to $someVar = 'abc'; $string = "{$someVar}"; - then $string becomes *abc*
Also, this being an integer (I suppose) there would be no need for the quotes, but it should still work (unlike the other way around, if you would want to enter a string without quotes).